# How do we determine queue and stack size while working on network processor?

Tags: networking

While working on a network processor, how can we determine the size of the queue and the stack.

Comment: Just an idea: accept some more answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have mainly used network processor as router while working on BTS development.

Most important thing while determining size is the speed of the processor and the rate at which packets enter/exit the NP.
Also important factor is the parallelism which needs to be maintained.

Like in case of BTS, KPI give a good idea of total voice/GPRS calls that need to be run at load conditions.Based on that calculate total number of queues and decide how many memory LW each queue will take to be properly identified.

Understand that my queue concept does not talk of catering to the actual data; actual voice would be stored in DRAM buffer handles whose other info would be catered by a queue.

Stack size on a NP i dont have much idea of; but again i am not sure if it is a configurable parameter; more to do with the lifetime of total variable along with thier size durign function calls